# Line-height inheritance

Tags: html, inheritance, css

I can't change my span element line-height, that is defined in body (I've tried using !important, as well as different line-height notation including font/line-height). Here's the code:

```
body {
    font: 16px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.pageBody.oferta > .cnt .columns ul span {
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

The problem is obviously that my spans line-height is 1.5

More to that web dev tool doesn't show that inheritance from body covers it (it's crossed in web dev tool then). There's lot of code on the site as well, but i don't think that it could affect line-height anyhow (so pasting it would be lot of spam).

Edit: Interesting thing i have found out: when i apply line-height bigger than 2, it starts to apply on the span.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `line-height` on a block container, not on `span`. For `span`, or for non-replaced inline elements in general, the height of the content area depends on the font and on the browser and generally makes provisions for descenders and ascenders; see [10.6.1 Inline, non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced) in the CSS 2.1 spec.

Even for a `div` element or other block element, your chances of tweaking the height down to 9px might be prevented by user settings, such as minimum font size set to something larger (an user option on Firefox; cannot be overridden by authors).

I don’t know how you inferred the line height, but my Firebug says, for a document constructed from your example, the computed line height as 9px but, in the Layout pane, the height as 13px. This is normal, by the CSS 2.1 principles.

Comment: Thanks a lot, display: block for span does  the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
span {
    line-height: 0.66; /* 66% of 1.5 ~= 1 
}
```

since line-height values are multiplied on nested elements you could obtain this with `0.66`. Another way to override the value is setting `line-height: normal` (but the real value [will change depending on the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height))

Answer (score -1):

You are missing unit part of the definiation
Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HWtDX/1/)