# Why doesn't vertical-align: middle work with input elements in a table-cell?

Tags: html, css, input, html-table, vertical-alignment

Here is my code:

```css
*               { vertical-align: top; margin: 0; }
td              { vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid red; }
td:nth-child(1) { line-height: 3em; }
td:nth-child(2) { line-height: 4em; }
td:nth-child(3) { line-height: 0.1em; }
p, input        { outline: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          Some vertically centered text.
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As one can see, the `p` is neatly vertically centered, as well as the `input` with `line-height: .1em`, while the `input` with `line-height: 4em` is moved to the top.

I did not find an explanation for this behaviour after lengthy research.

I set up a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dlenne/8xapwz11/14/.

Answer (score 6):

You've set `vertical-align: middle` on the `td`, each of which is a parent of an `input` element.

But the `vertical-align` property is not inherited ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#leading)).

So, one solution is to apply the rule directly to the inputs:

```css
*               { vertical-align: top; margin: 0; }
td              { vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid red; }
td:nth-child(1) { line-height: 3em; }
td:nth-child(2) { line-height: 4em; }
td:nth-child(3) { line-height: .1em; }
p, input        { outline: 1px solid green; }
input           { vertical-align: middle; }               /* new */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Some vertically centered text.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

An alternative solution simply bypasses the `line-height` rules by switching the `display` value of the inputs from `inline` to `block`.

```css
*               { vertical-align: top; margin: 0; }
td              { vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid red; }
td:nth-child(1) { line-height: 3em; }
td:nth-child(2) { line-height: 4em; }
td:nth-child(3) { line-height: .1em; }
p, input        { outline: 1px solid green; }
input           { display: block; }               /* new */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Some vertically centered text.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

References:

- [Understanding `vertical-align`, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/)
- [10.8.1 Leading and half-leading](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#leading) (W3C definitions for `line-height` and `vertical-align`)
- [Line-height inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615425/line-height-inheritance)

Comment: First i thank you all for your very qualified answers!
Secondly i had the suspicion, that there is a virtual or implicit object around the input element, to which the line-height property is applied, and that has its vertical-align-property set to "top". Which is basically what Oriol wrote in the  next post, the line box.
Another example of CSS beeing not exactly self explanatory but needing a pretty detailed implicit model in your head to make any sense of its rules...

Comment: A billion times upvote...  I've worked with vertical-align here or there several times over many projects, and it always seemed to give me problems, and finally I found this answer here which made it all so clear "But the vertical-align property is not inheritable."  So, after picking my jaw off the floor, I was happy to replace any instance of `td{vertical-align: whatever;}` with `td *{vertical-align: whatever;}` for the same effect I always thought I was getting with the previous.  Thank you so much for this!  I look forward to so much less confusion over this property in the future.

Comment: @VoidKing, I'm glad I could help. BTW, it also helps to remember that `vertical-align` only works on `table-cell` and `inline-level` elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 2):

Since the cell has `vertical-align: middle`, its contents will be aligned to the middle of the cell.

But in this case it's not noticeable, because the contents occupy all the cell vertically.

That's because the [`line-height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) property sets the minimum height of a [line box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box), and you use a very tall value

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
  line-height: 4em;
}
```

Then, the input is an inline-level element. So its vertical alignment with respect to that line box will be given by the [`vertical-align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) of the input.

```css
* {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

If you want to align the input at the middle of the cell, you should use `vertical-align: middle` on the input to align it to the middle of its line box, which is aligned to the middle of the cell.

```css
input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
* {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}
td, input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
td:nth-child(1) {
  line-height: 3em;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  line-height: 4em;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
  line-height: 0.1em;
}
p, input {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        Some vertically centered text.
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of this :

```
*{vertical-align: top;}
```

When you make the line height bigger than the *td*(parent) it i.e. `input`(child) scales out and hence follows: `vertical-align: top;` rather than `vertical-align: center;`