# How can I perfectly align text inside its own line/box?

Tags: css

I know there are a lot of different ways to align something inside a box, there is the transform hack, the display table, flexbox, etc. However, if I have a label and I give it the same padding on the top side and on the bottom side, it still is not perfectly centered. I guess this is because of the line height.

[image]

There must be a way to do this constantly between font-families, sizes, etc right? Vertical-align center does not do anything, with is to bad.

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.file-input {
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.file-input+label {
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s background-color ease-in-out;
}

.file-input:focus+label,
.file-input+label:hover {
  background-color: #e53935;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  <title>Generate Video Thumbnail</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="file" name="file-input" id="file-input" class="file-input" />
    <label for="file-input">Choose a file</label>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

PS: For the love of god, no JavaScript.

Comment: since each font is different I don't think we can even define *constantly between font-families* unless you have some way to precise this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically center text that has no descenders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272234/vertically-center-text-that-has-no-descenders)

Comment: Well, all I want is to perfectly center some text inside its own box... This is way harder then I think it should be. I can fix this by looking at the rendered box height and setting that as line-height. But that is way to manual.

Comment: *I want is to perfectly center some text inside its own box.* --> you need to define the *perfectly*, based on what? how you will say it's centred? because actually it's *perfectly* centred for me.

Comment: What do you mean I need to define? I want the exact amount of pixels on the top side as in the bottom side. With at the moment it is not. There is more space on the bottom side. If you zoom in my picture you will see the line box and you will see that there is empty space on the bottom side.

Comment: _“There must be a way to do this constantly between font-families, sizes, etc right?“_ - not right, because this depends very much on the characteristics of the specific font. _“Vertical-align center does not do anything, with is to bad.”_ - no, that is just _to be expected_, because that’s not what that property is for in the first place.

Comment: @VeraPerrone did you think about the letters `jpy`? and also about `Â Ê` ?

Comment: Well there is this way that works on every font: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: _“Well there is this way that works on every font: ...”_ - you do realize that this uses four variables that are very specific to the used font, right?

Comment: Yes, however, how many fonts do you plan to use on a website? I am just looking for a solution that is not context dependent like setting a fixed hight. I don't mind getting font specs 1 time. The only reason I asked the question in the first place is because I tough people could come up with a simpler solution with seems to not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this, this is the concept of the trick:

```
.yourLabel{
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 padding:0 5px;
 }
```

As you can see, responsive and works with any font choice.

You can play around with the padding values, as long the height and line height have the same value, it will be centered.

Vertical-align doesn't work on text input fields/labels.

There you go:

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/WYMqWJ?editors=1100

Comment: Yes... but it means I need to give it a height. Is there really no other way? I already knew this solution.

Comment: `Vertical-align doesn't work on text input fields/labels.` --> it doeas work because those element are inline level element

Comment: As far I am aware, this is the most consistent and least hacky solutions. I have ran into this very issue before, save yourself the time.
You could run a JS and get computed values or offsetHeight or clientHeight(see, the nightmare already starts here, and you would have to consider box sizing properties etc) , and then set the line height accordingly on load. Much more hacky(though I like it), with this, all you need is some CSS rules for various devices.
In other words, hobby projects, I would do the JS solution, in production, the above.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you are right, it is more complicated, sorry for the poor wording, I found this insightful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848273/why-doesnt-vertical-align-middle-work-with-input-elements-in-a-table-cell
Cheers

Comment: I will go with this solution, I am just giving it some time hoping some CSS wizard has another solution.

Comment: @VeraPerrone, likewise, always all ears to learn new approaches.
As examples, I was always hoping something like intersection Observer and El.animate would happen native, and speaking of the devil, suddenly, they became reality(poor support, though)>;-)